# Extract date(1 or 2 digit), month(1 or 2 digit) and year(2 or 4 digit) from a date string (for different pattern)

Tags: javascript, regex

My app have a text-field where user can enter the date manually. Also, my app have preferences to select the date pattern like M D Y or D M Y or Y M D.

1) Assume, app is using M D Y pattern currently. So user can enter the date in the following formats:
09/14/2015 or 9/14/2015 or 09/14/15 or 9-14-2015 or 9-14/2015

Here I want to extract the...

```
month => 09 (or 9)
day => 14
year => 2015 (or 15)
```

Note: Since app is using M D Y pattern, if user enter the date in D M Y pattern (like 14/09/2015) or Y M Y pattern (like 2015/09/14) we should not match it.

I have the below regex

```
var dateString = "09/14/2015";
var match = dateString.match(/(\d{1,2})[\/ \.-](\d{1,2})[\/ \.-](\d{2,4}).*/);
```

but its not matching my expectation, because it allows D M Y and Y M Y pattern too.

2) In the same way, if app is using D M Y pattern I want to extract the day, month and year. (it should not allow M D Y or Y M D)

3)  In the same way, if app is using Y M D pattern I want to extract the year, month and day. (it should not allow M D Y or D M Y)

Can someone fix it for me? thank you!

Comment: For starters, I'd change the ".*"s in your pattern to pick up only "/".  The ".*" means any characters - e.g. it could well match "/14/2"

Comment: so try changing the ".*" to something like "[/-]" (the square brackets mean any of the individual characters).  Note : the "-" has come AFTER the "/", since "[-/]"will mean "all except /"

Comment: (thanks racraman). I have checked by replacing ".*"'s with [\/ \.-] but its not meeting by expectation.

Comment: How "not meeting"???  It extracts the three parts of the date;  that's all you can expect a regex to do.  As Jodevan says below, you cannot expect the regex to automatically determine which part is day and which is month.  All you can do is set the Pattern according to the user's format preference, set day,month,year variables from the match based on that preference, and let your date validation routine handle anything further.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
^((0?[13578]|10|12)(-|\/)(([1-9])|(0[1-9])|([12])([0-9]?)|(3[01]?))(-|\/)((19)([2-9])(\d{1})|(20)([01])(\d{1})|([8901])(\d{1}))|(0?[2469]|11)(-|\/)(([1-9])|(0[1-9])|([12])([0-9]?)|(3[0]?))(-|\/)((19)([2-9])(\d{1})|(20)([01])(\d{1})|([8901])(\d{1})))$
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Humaira. It's matching M D Y formats, but I couldn't extract the day, month, year. Is there any way to get that?

Comment: this type or thing you have find in your programing code like split your value width `/` and access your array

Comment: please except if my ans make you comfortable.

Comment: thanks again Humaira. We can do the split, but the date may come with two separators like "9/14-2015" as I mentioned the description.

Comment: then you can check `/` position of this string if this is grater than 3 mean `/` is located after date and split it make array that have in index 0 month and date and index 1 contain year then split again index 0 with `-`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to provide a full answer to your question just by using regular expressions. They are meant to recognize patterns. In several situations, by just recognizing a pattern it's possible to tell that this pattern represents valid data. This is not always true, though and your question is an example.

Think a bit: is "15-02-29" valid?
The answer is: it depends! 
This single string can represent:

- 15/feb/2029 - valid;
- ??/2nd/2029 - invalid;
- 2015/feb/29 - invalid, since 2015 is not a leap year;
- ... and so on.

So this goes way beyond regular expressions are meant to. They are just dumb string recognizers.
The solution? You can even use the regular expressions to extract the values from the passed string, but you'll have to write some extra code to validate what these values mean.

Comment: (Thanks Jodevan). First I want to extract the day, month and year, once I get these values then I can validate them.

Answer (score 0):

The date 06/05/2015 could mean "June 5th 2015" or "May 6th 2015" either way the date is valid and should be valid for both MDY and DMY so they cant be mutually exclusive. Once the user selects a format you have to trust them to get it right.(in some cases)

Have a look at the javascript library [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/)
You can use it to parse string dates by expected format.

`moment("9/14/2015", ["MM-DD-YYYY", "YYYY MM DD", "DD-MM-YYYY"]);`

I set up a little playground: http://jsfiddle.net/me2loveit2/knfjepty/

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. ***`The date 06/05/2015 could mean "June 5th 2015" or "May 6th 2015" either way the date is valid `*** => Since my app will give the (current) date pattern, I can choose correct date in this case. (Just I need to extract the day, month and year as I described in the description). And more over I don't want to use any library for this.

Comment: ok say the app expects MDY but the user puts in DMY by accident, in my example the app will assume it is MDY and get the wrong date. You can't know what format it actually is if it matches both formats(and it will if  you want to accept all valid dates). Because of that you also can't match MDY but not DMY at the same time